# how to display scope_identity on textbox in c# using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've been stuck at retrieving the getting the last identity of the primary key. I use the scope_identity function after the insert statement.

Here's my table = userinfo

```
id int primary key identity(1,1),
username varchar(50) not null,
password varchar(50) not null
```

My stored procedure

```
create procedure add_u
@username varchar(50),
@password varchar(50)
as
insert into userinfo (username,password) values (@username,@password)
select scope_identity();
```

My c# code
I used the linq to sql class

```
public static void Add_user (userinfo u)
{
db = new dataclasses1context();
db.add_u(u.username,u.password);
}
```

My form code

```
userinfo ui = new userinfo();
ui.username = textbox1.text;
ui.password = textbox2.text;
class1.Add_User(ui);
textbox3.text = ui.id.tostring();
```

But it doesn't work.

I searched for solutions on Google specifically stackoverflow they used OLEdb I work on Linq.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/C-6-0-NET-4-6-Framework/dp/1484213335/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1472909352&sr=8-2&keywords=entity+framework+6

Comment: Try `select scope_identity() as id`. EF expects a named field to be returned.